# Prisma Delete: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'model')

Tags: mongodb, prisma, next.js13

I am using NextJS client with Prisma (mongoDB). I am trying to create a delete function:

deleteEvent.ts

```
import prisma from "@/app/libs/prismadb";

export default async function deleteEvent(eventId: string) {
  try {
console.log(eventID);
    const deletedEvent = await prisma.events.delete({
      where: {
        id: eventId,
      },
    });
    console.log("Deleted Event:", deletedEvent);
    return deletedEvent;
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.error("Error deleting event:", error);
    throw new Error(error);
  }
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
deleteEvent.ts Error deleting event: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'events')
```

The function is called onClick of delete button:

```
const onClick = async (deleteId: string) => {
    try {
      await deleteEvent(deleteId);
      toast.success("Event deleted!");
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error("Something went wrong");
    }
  };
```

DeleteID is logging on the console with no issues and is the correct id that exists in the database.

My other prisma.events.findMany and prisma.user.findUnique functions are working perfectly fine which suggests that the Prisma client is able to interact with the models.

I can't see any syntax errors and the user does not need to be authenticated (as that is done on the frontend).

Can anyone help?